# Are there universal alternatives to window.onload without using frameworks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

In [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283875/what-are-my-options-to-avoid-this-error-and-document-write-in-internet-explorer) I learned of a bug in my JavaScript related to using appendChild on the BODY element before the DOMReady event was fired.

I was able to resolve this by wrapping my code in a window.onload event. Reading up on this, I have learned that window.onload only supports a single listener, and I can't guarantee I am not clobbering someone else's listener or that someone else's listener is not clobbering mine.

Looking at the source for `$(document).ready(function(){});`, I realize there is perhaps a lot that goes into the simplicity of that syntax.

Is there a universal way for me to wait for the DOMReady event without using jQuery or another JS library? While it seems like that would do the trick, I would prefer not to have any dependencies on a third party library in order for my code to work correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(nameOfSomeFunctionToRunOnPageLoad);
addLoadEvent(function() {
  /* more code to run on page load */
});
```

which wraps the existing `onload` in a new function with an additional function. This is taken from http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/onloads/

However, for **doing it on document ready and not onload** (different things, onload is when everything is downloaded where ready is when the document are loaded) **look at this question**: [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Comment: The above breaks when using Mixpanel; you need to include an event parameter. See: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/5227403

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
document.onpageshow= new function() {
//(Code here)
}
```

You can also replace "onpageshow" with "onload" for better compatibility.

This may also be helpful:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener